# Potential Issues making chmod 777 on a directory located in s3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, chmod, s3fs

Suppose I have an s3 bucket mounted on my ec2 instance. **My goal is to keep my static files on s3 and access them from my app which is on the ec2**, so I have done everything as it should be but the problem is my app is not being able to access the objects that are on the mounted folder or in the s3. I need to give the mounted folder `chmod 777` permission every time I upload a new folder or file.

- As I have mounted the folder with `allow_other` tag, so it shouldn't have to give permission explicitly. It should have allowed the app to edit or use the folders as instructed.
- But it's not acting like that so I need to give `777` permission explicitly.

**So my question is** I am giving 777 permission to a folder which is in the s3 so what are the risk of doing this?

My app is secured, it's solid, so the app or the front end is good. But what is the *risk of having a folder with 777 rwx permission*, which could only be viewed from the app?

Comment: Amazon S3 is an object storage service, not a filesystem. It is not recommended to 'mount' an Amazon S3 bucket on a computer, especially for Production usage. Instead, you should access Amazon S3 via API calls or with the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

Comment: I am mounting it on my ec2 instance. well, the files are being accessed infrequently. I just need the storage for my extra files.

Answer (score 0):

What is the access policy of the s3 bucket?

If only the app can read and only the app can write to the bucket then you can argue that this is as secure or insecure as having the same permissions on the local disk of the application.

Comment: S3 has public access, I have given s3 all the services of public access. Overall i want to know is it safe? well the bucket is being accessed via my app. So if there any chance of any security risks?

Comment: Can you post the Bucket Policy? (Exclude the bucket name)
It is definitely not "overall safe" given only the information you posted so far.
It is definitely bad practice and probably unnecessary to mount s3 as local filesystem in order to provide static content to web clients.
If you upload files to s3 in any other way than mounting to fs you won't have to worry so much about file permissions.

Comment: i am enabling all the services for s3 on my bucket policy list

Comment: Can you paste the policy?

Comment: {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1111",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "private_id",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::sample/*"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: That looks like an invalid Bucket Policy, missing something in Action and Principal fields?